# Nested data from user Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this data from console from my backend:

```js
  user { courses:
   { createdAt: 2017-10-24T14:35:17.562Z,
     _id: 59ef4fcf941e450ccc132f13,
     title: 'My course',
        __v: 0 },
  _id: 5b38e3bc9dbf9113560a2d4c,
  username: 'marcos',
  email: 'marcos@marcos.com'
```

In user page show only: _id, username and email, but array course not appear.
But I get not show in the user page, someone can help me about this?

Comment: Can you please update your post with your component code?

Comment: In this, have everything:
https://gist.github.com/mskinho/dea7b4e710b8664c3c1259ab790c9272

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's working. I converted obj json in array in my BackEnd.
In the Frontend I used {{courses.title}}
thanks reggards!

Answer (score 0):

Courses is an object, it is not an array, how are you accessing it?

```
user.courses.createdAt
user.courses._id
```

Is the syntax to access the properties of a sub object.

Answer (score 0):

Courses is an object, you need to access using the property you want to bind

```
<hello name="{{ user.username }}"></hello>
<p>
  Your email is {{user.email}} 
  your course is {{user.courses.title}}
</p>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/showingjson-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: This would be the correct way, but not list this way in my console in frontEnd, list this way:
user
:
course
:
["59ef4fcf941e450ccc132f13"]
email
:
"marcos@msantana.com.br"
password
:
"$2a$10$ZwtV9drpSEF7y8swFsTM3..DCT80AFMib0EAnJgFXhJmgUR5.tHH."
username
:
"marcos"
not any information about course {title: my course, ...}

Comment: Hera are my back and front end: https://gist.github.com/mskinho/dea7b4e710b8664c3c1259ab790c9272
I can't understand why don't work.

Comment: what do you mean by backend and front end

Comment: I sent email for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access course object using the property name

```
    <div *ngFor="let user of userList">
        {{user._id}}
        {{user.username}}
        {{user.email}}

        <p>
            {{user.courses.createdAt}}
            {{user.courses._id}}
            {{user.courses.title}}
            {{user.courses.__v}}
        </p>
    </div>
```

This is how user list object can be access.
If it is only single object then it can be access by property name

```
    <div>
        {{user._id}}
        {{user.username}}
        {{user.email}}

        <p>
            {{user.courses.createdAt}}
            {{user.courses._id}}
            {{user.courses.title}}
            {{user.courses.__v}}
        </p>
    </div>
```